# How to run Spock Integration test on Grails

Tags: grails, spock

Technology stack for my project is Grails 3.2.3,Groovy 2.4.7 ,Gradle 3.2.1,GORM and IDE is Intellij and backend is MongoDB.
I have implemented Spock Integraction test class TestControllerSpec and want to run single Spock integration test 
what are the configuration changes required in order to run single testcase and how?

```
@Integration
@Rollback
class TestControllerSpec extends Specification {

    @Unroll
    void "temp listObjects"(){        
        def result   
        def params = [id:  '123']
        when:
        result = controller.index(10)
        then:
        result == null
        result.size()==0
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're in IntelliJ, can you not just right-click anywhere within the specification and tell it to run that test?

Comment: Have you checked the [documentation](https://grails.org/plugin/spock) on the grails-spock integration? Gradle can execute single tests using command line parameter patterns ([gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#test_filtering), [examples](http://snippets.bitshifts.com/2016/03/19/running-single-test.html)) such as `gradle test --tests org.gradle.SomeTest.someSpecificFeature`

Comment: If this is from within IntelliJ, you can use the intellij-gradle integration and run the 'test' task with the above `--tests` parameter from within intellij.

Comment: The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
  at build_cib62r8qsn00vq0cqu7xznhk6.run(C:\MyProject\build.gradle:23).
   
          ***  Even line#23 commenting  //apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-web" also not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use command line:

```
grails test-app -integration
```

or for the particular test:

```
grails test-app com.best.company.BestTestClass -integration
```

Comment: getting below error ****************  Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Shutdown in progress
        at java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks.add(ApplicationShutdownHooks.java:66)
        at java.lang.Runtime.addShutdownHook(Runtime.java:211)

Comment: at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.io.file.FileCleaner.forceDeleteOnExit(FileCleaner.java:52)
        at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.io.file.Files.forceDelete(Files.java:125)
        at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.extract.ExtractedFileSets.delete(ExtractedFileSets.java:76)
        at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.store.ExtractedArtifactStore.removeFileSet(ExtractedArtifactStore.java:147)

Comment: at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.runtime.Executable.stop(Executable.java:77)
        at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.runtime.Executable$JobKiller.run(Executable.java:90)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
:mergeTestReports

Comment: From the stacktrace info it seems to be some issue with reports files deletion. Is flapdoodle somehow related to mongo? I believe that the answer could be found in the source code of the classes from the given stacktrace.